# Bind bool to visibility property

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp

I've searched this question a lot. But, it seems no solutions are working for me. I don't get any errors but I've added a breakpoint to my IValueConverter. The breakpoint does not ever get triggered. Why is it not using my converter? All I want to do is use view model strategy for visibility binding of a UI element (in this case a checkbox). Any help is appreciated.

**IValueConverter:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace Test_Tool.Common
{
    public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) => (bool)value ^ (parameter as string ?? string.Empty).Equals("Reverse") ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) => (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible ^ (parameter as string ?? string.Empty).Equals("Reverse");
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Page
    x:Class="Test_Tool.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Test_Tool"
    xmlns:converter="using:Test_Tool.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <converter:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="cvt" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Pivot x:Name="rootPivot" Title="Test Tool" >
            <PivotItem Header="Test Selection">
                <StackPanel>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="dppCheckBox" Content="DPP" Margin="5,8,5,5" Visibility="{Binding IsDirect, Converter={StaticResource cvt}}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test_Tool.ViewModels
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //Localized private vars
        private bool _isDirect;

        //Public vars for bindings
        public bool IsDirect
        {
            get
            {
                return _isDirect;
            }
            set
            {
                _isDirect = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            //Any Initialization
            IsDirect = false;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**MainPage:**

```
using DM_API_Test_Tool.ViewModels;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace Test_Tool
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPageViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.ViewModel = new MainPageViewModel();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing a clr namespace declaration instead of a simple using?

Instead of:
xmlns:converter="using:Test_Tool.Common"

Use:
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:Test_Tool.Common"

Comment: @exceptionthrown Unfortunately that didn't fix it. The checkbox is still visible and the breakpoint within my converter is never hit

Comment: You might need to specify what property has changed. Instead of: OnPropertyChanged() Use: OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsDirect)).

Comment: @exceptionthrown Same result unfortunately

Comment: Last thing that pops into my head is to simplify your converter. Instead of trying to xor just have two converters (a normal and inverse bool to visibility). If you change you current version's convert method to something like this does it work at all?


public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ((bool)value)
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }

            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

Comment: @exceptionthrown I don't see a difference between the code you have pasted in?

Comment: Will this do?

public object Convert(object value,Type targetType,object parameter,string language)
{if((bool)value)
{return Visibility.Visible;}else
{return Visibility.Collapsed;}}
public object ConvertBack(object value,Type targetType,object parameter,string language)
{if((Visibility)value==Visibility.Visible)
{return true;}else
{return false;}}

Comment: @Kyle I just changed your `Convert` Method to this and it works perfect for me. `public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            var returnval = (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            return returnval;
        }`

Comment: Where and how are you setting the *DataContext*?

Comment: Pivot class is the ItemsControl. So the DataContext of your CheckBox is NOT the MainPageViewModel, it's the content of the PivotItem. So you are actually binding to the wrong object and so the binding fails.

Comment: @Romasz I've updated my question with the code. Pavel can you elaborate more on how I would alter setting my DataContext/ViewModel?

Comment: Your problem is that you haven't set any *DataContext*, either for your page/pivot and you are not using ItemsSource. Without *DataContext* binding doesn't know where to search for your property. The simple fix (probably not the best) can be to put at the end of MainPage constuctor: `this.DataContext = ViewModel;`. BTW - currently in UWP you don't need to use converter for bool to visibility - xaml has internal converter.

Comment: @Romasz That was the solution. Just add DataContext. Thank you so much.

Comment: My issue was that the Visibility property has values of Visible and Collapsed. I just returned either value as a string with the binding and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
namespace Test_Tool.ViewModels
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _isDirect = false;
        public bool IsDirect
        {
            get
            {
                return _isDirect;
            }
            set
            {
                set { SetField(ref _isDirect, value, "isDirect"); }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

this should work now.

However I prefer the `BindableBase` method more (save the content below in a new class and call it something like `BindableBase.cs`)

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Mvvm
{
    public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
        {
            if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;

            storage = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (eventHandler != null)
            {
                eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then your `ViewModel` would be reduced to

```
using Mvvm;

namespace Test_Tool
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private bool _isDirect = false;
        public bool IsDirect
        {
            get { return _isDirect; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _isDirect, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

and one last thing: In your `MainPage.xaml` you want to bind to `rootPivot`, so you call

```
rootPivot.DataContext = null;
rootPivot.DataContext = new MainPageViewModel();
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using external convertor library. 
I found this nuget package:[click here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/suren37.Library.Convertors/)

This library is very simple to use, first install the nuget package and insert:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFUI.Views.MainWindow"
    ...
    xmlns:convertor="clr-namespace:suren37.convertor;assembly=suren37.convertor"
    ...>
```

as namespace at the top of the view and you can now bind a boolean value to the visibility as

```
<CheckBox Grid.Row="1" IsChecked="{Binding IsVisibile}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="8 0" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="This text becomes visible on checked"
                   Visibility="{Binding IsVisibile, Converter={convertor:BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                   Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
```

To check out the working sample visit the github page, [here](https://github.com/suren37/wpf_convetors).